# Dynamic div id with li in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am doing a quiz section and trying to remove a class of li of its parent dynamic div

This is the reference I followed [ https://www.msn.com/en-ie/entertainment/quiz/quiz-how-well-do-you-know-friends/ar-BBsDVvo#page=2 ]
Here I have looped a div, which is containing a question and its four options, below code is that dynamic div

Image for the quiz section

[image]

```
<div id="login-1">   
   <p>Which of the following ancient Indian sages did not make substantial contribution to the YOGCRA (Yogachara) philosophical tradition?</p> </h3>
      <div class="q-option mtp40">
         <ul>                                         
             <li id="opt-361" data-id="361" class="qoption selected" data-m ="364"> Vasubandhu</li>                                          
             <li id="opt-362" data-id="362" class="qoption" data-m ="364"> Dinnaga</li> 
             <li id="opt-363" data-id="363" class="qoption" data-m ="364"> Dharmakirti</li> 
             <li id="opt-364" data-id="364" class="qoption answered" data-m ="364"> Nagarjuna</li>         
         </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

when I click on an option (li) of its corresponding question and containing classes like "qoption selected" or "qoption answered", I want to remove that "qoption" class, so that it cant selected any other answer once it selected once

This is what  i have tried

```php
$(document).on('click', '.qoption', function() { 
   var choosedid = $(this).data('id');  
   var correctid = $(this).attr('data-m');                      
   if (choosedid == correctid) {
      $('#opt-'+choosedid).addClass('answered');
   } else {
      $('#opt-'+choosedid).addClass('selected');
      $('#opt-'+correctid).addClass('answered');
   }                           
   $(".next").show();
   var total_question = 3;
   for (i = 0; i < total_question.length; i++) { 
      if( ('#login-'+total_question[i] 'li').hasClass('selected') || $('#login-'+total_question[i] 'li').hasClass('answered')) {
        $('#login-'+total_question[i] 'li').removeClass('qoption');                     
      }
}
```

Comment: you have many syntax errors in your code. Please clean it and format it before posting a question. Plus your description is unclear. `Trying to remove a class of li of its parent dynamic div` so you want to remove the class of the `li` or it's `parent` ? and `total_question` variable is undefined.

Comment: i want to remove li class "qoption" where li class is "selected" or "answered" @Mihai T

Comment: one more thing i want to tell here .. you should remove answer id from that li this is not good practice..on click of li you can call ajax request and from the server you can validate

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it in a single line

```
$(document).on('click', '.qoption', function() { 
    var choosedid = $(this).data('id');  
    var correctid = $(this).attr('data-m');   

    $('#opt-'+choosedid).removeClass('qoption');

    if (choosedid == correctid) {
        $('#opt-'+choosedid).addClass('answered');
    } else {
        $('#opt-'+choosedid).addClass('selected');
        $('#opt-'+correctid).addClass('answered');
    } 

    $(".next").show();
});
```

Comment: No, i want to remove li class "qoption" where li class is "selected" or "answered" @Mihai T

Comment: on which action you want to remove the class?

Comment: when we click on option that means in li @ma_dev_15

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.qoption', function() {
  $('.answered').removeClass('qoption');
  $('.selected').removeClass('qoption');
}

Comment: No it will not work, can you please check my post again

Comment: $('#login-1 li').removeClass('qoption') 
This will work , but how to dynamic with for loop like  $('#login-1 li').removeClass('qoption'),$('#login-2 li').removeClass('qoption') and so on...

Comment: $('div[id$="login-"] li')  you can use regex

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    $(document).on('click', '.qoption', function () {
        var choosedid = $(this).data('id');
        var correctid = $(this).attr('data-m');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        if (choosedid == correctid) {
            $(this).addClass('answered');
        } 
        $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('qoption');
        $(".next").show();
    });
```

Comment: i need somethink like, 
$('#login-1 li').removeClass('qoption') This will work , but how to dynamic with for loop like $('#login-1 li').removeClass('qoption'),$('#login-2 li').removeClass('qoption') and so on..

Comment: in that div take a class example  <div id="login-1"   class='login-div'>    then 

  var total_question = $('login-div li').length;

then rest as it is...

Comment: $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('qoption'); , it works thanks@soubhagya